# Determining the bias state vector when combining qubits?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

I'm trying to learn about quantum computing from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate). But I'm stumbling on the "**Bias State Vector**" term they use for the combination of qubits. I understand this is some operation on the components of a qubit, but what is the operation?

If I have two qubits $A$ and $B$

$A = m |0\rangle + n|1\rangle$

$B = o|0\rangle + p|1\rangle$

I want to combine these qubits into a single qubit with the bias states

$C = w|00\rangle + x|01\rangle + y|10\rangle + z|11\rangle$

What operation accomplishes this? Is it just simple addition? Multiplication? Dot Product? I assume this is a non-trivial operation as the qubits magnitude must remain constant.

So for example (this is wrong, and what I'm trying to learn):

$C = (m+o)|00\rangle + (m+p)|01\rangle +(n+o)|10\rangle + (n+p)|11\rangle$

How does this extend to $n$ quibts?

Comment: Do you mean "basis state"?

Comment: How dyou calculate w,x,y,z for the C qubit (combination of A and B, give their states m,n,o,and p)

Comment: double post :(  .

Answer (score 2):

$C$ is determined by taking the [tensor product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of $A$ and $B$. $A$ and $B$ are in the vector space, and you want to get all possible combinations of values of $A$ and $B$, which are $00,01,10,11$.